# How do I evaluate this integral using Cauchy's theorem?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, mathematical-physics, cauchy-integral-formula

I have a physic paper to do and one of the question is to demonstrate this equality using Cauchy's theorem :

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i\zeta^2 sgn \varphi''(k_0) } d\zeta = \sqrt{\Pi} e^{\frac{i\Pi}{4}*sng \varphi''(k_0)}$$

sng being the sign function

What I have used to try to solve this is this calculation :

With $x=\zeta$ and $a=-i*sng\varphi''(k_0)$, we have :

\begin{align*}
I &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-ax^2 } dx \\ 
I^2 &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-ax^2 } dx \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-ay^2 } dy \\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-ax^2 } e^{-ay^2 } dxdy \\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-a(x^2+y^2) } dxdy \\
&=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-ar^2} rdrd\theta \\
&=2\pi \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-u} \frac{du}{2a} \\
I^2 &=\frac{\pi}{a}
\end{align*}
So $$I=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}$$

Therefore
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i\zeta^2 sgn \varphi''(k_0) } d\zeta = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{-i*sgn \varphi''(k_0)}} = \sqrt{\pi * i * sgn   \varphi''(k_0)}$$

The result I have is far from what I'm looking for. I also know that the fact that *a* is complex might make my calculations false, but I have to say that I'm quite lost. I didn't understand how to use Cauchy's theorem for this problem.

If anyone could help me I would be very greatful ! :)

Thanks in advance and have a good day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about the fact that $a \notin \mathbb{R}$ change a few things. I will set $b = \mathrm{sgn}(\varphi''(k_0)) \in \{\pm 1\}$ hence $a = ib$. Moreover, the square root of a complex number that is not in $\mathbb{R}_+$ is not well defined. You have to choose between two possiblities and you have no canonical way to choose one more than the other. Therefore, unless you precise what you mean, $\sqrt{i\pi\mathrm{sgn}(\varphi''(k_0))}$ is non sens.

The main problem is that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{ibx^2} \, dx$ exists in the sens that when $b \in \mathbb{R}^*$,
$$
\int_A^B \cos(bx^2) \, dx \underset{A,B \rightarrow -\infty,+\infty}{\longrightarrow} I_1 \in \mathbb{R}, \qquad \int_A^B \sin(bx^2) \, dx \underset{A,B \rightarrow -\infty,+\infty}{\longrightarrow} I_2 \in \mathbb{R},
$$
but $x \mapsto e^{ibx^2}$ is not integrable on $\mathbb{R}$ in the sens of Lebesgue in the sens that,
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} \left|e^{ibx^2}\right| \, dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} 1 \, dx = +\infty.
$$
It can cause some problems. For example, you can't use Fubini theorem so easily like you did when you computed $I^2$. For $b = 1$, you have,
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} \cos(x^2) \, dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}, \qquad \int_{\mathbb{R}} \sin(x^2) \, dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}.
$$
Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral for more details. They can be computed, as you said, using Cauchy formula (look at the paragraph "Limits as $x$ approaches infinity") by integrating $x \mapsto e^{ix^2}$ on a well chosen domain. Now, for parity reasons,
$$
I = \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{ibx^2} \, dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} + ib\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} = \sqrt{\pi}\frac{1 + ib}{\sqrt{2}} = \sqrt{\pi}e^{ib\frac{\pi}{4}}.
$$

Comment: It really helped, thanks a lot ! :)